# Postgres, trim all text field in all table, before insert and before update without trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, trim

Is it possible to set the database (PostgreSQL v 14) that for each insert or update on the text fields execute a trim?

This action would save me from creating 2 triggers for each table (trigger before insert and before update) with trim control on all text fields.

Comment: You don't need two triggers per table. A single trigger defined as `before update or insert` would do.

Comment: ok, but I have to do this trigger and a specific function for all tables. it is not efficient

Answer (score 0):

add another generated column. Obviously it will take some storage.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    src text,
    trim_src text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (regexp_replace(regexp_replace(src, '^\s+', ''), '\s+$', '')) STORED
);

INSERT INTO test (src)
    VALUES (' hello world   ')
RETURNING
    *;

INSERT INTO test (src)
    VALUES ('   hello world   ')
RETURNING
    *;

SELECT
    *,
    char_length(trim_src)
FROM
    test;
```

return:

```
        src        |  trim_src   | char_length
-------------------+-------------+-------------
  hello world      | hello world |          11
    hello world    | hello world |          11
(2 rows)
```

But you cannot directly update trim_src. you need update src, then trim_src will be automatically updated.